# I just received my Stack Overflow Weekly Newsletter, and the "Top new questions this week" are a bunch of low vote, low activity questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, newsletter

I just cracked open the my weekly newsletter subscription, and instead of a bunch of interesting questions as per usual, I received this list of questions under the "Top new questions this week":

- [Need assistance with SQL query for data extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491095/need-assistance-with-sql-query-for-data-extract?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)
- [Advanced 301 redirect for an entire site at site root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491112/advanced-301-redirect-for-an-entire-site-at-site-root?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)
- [How to update data in database with CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491120/how-to-updating-data-into-database?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)
- [Custom Segue Animation Flicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491134/custom-segue-animation-flicker?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)
- [Heroku and Leiningen: where did my files go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491141/heroku-and-leiningen-where-did-my-files-go?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)
- [Bigquery Stream: Missing data after new table created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491143/bigquery-stream-missing-data-after-new-table-created?newsletter=1&nlcode=250%7c519f)

I haven't changed any of my subscription settings recently, and the "Greatest hits from previous weeks" and "Can you answer these?" sections seem to be accurate.

Has something gone bonkers?

Comment: cross site duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242723/the-newsletter-is-suddenly-calling-questions-with-low-votes-low-views-and-no-an

Comment: Indeed, so it's not just SO. Glad I'm not alone :)

Comment: Yep, no duplicate code-blocks, so whoever pushed this feature introduced it network-wide....

Comment: I usually just ignore that NL most of the times :-P ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This was an interesting bug, we had a regression in our hot sorting algorithm that is produced by our API.  The newsletters consume this API which is why it became apparent in our newsletter emails.  Expect the next newsletter to be the highest quality newsletter you have ever seen (I may be exaggerating a bit).

Comment: status completed here too? [The newsletter is suddenly calling questions with low votes, low views and no answers "top new questions this week"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242723)

Comment: Just received my newsletter -- it's back to normal. Thanks!